# es6 in Node.js with Babel using import and IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, commonjs

When using es6 import feature in Node.js there is a problem with modules written with commonjs module format. I use babel-register to run the code.
For example I want to use named exports from express module and I write:

```
import * as express from "express";
let app = express();
```

I also use TypeScript type definitions with typings and they work this way. But this code fails to run saying that express() is not a function.
When I write as if I use default export like:

```
import express from "express";
let app = express();
```

It works, but IntelliSense is not available.

What is the problem with this?

Comment: Have you tried the steps from [https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/ES6-IntelliSense-Preview-in-NTVS-1.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/ES6-IntelliSense-Preview-in-NTVS-1.1)?

Comment: I'm working with Visual Studio Code, but it's not the problem of IDE.The problem is not with IntelliSense, I think it is Babel.
Importing with <import * as express from "express"> must import all named exports, which is the case with express and many other modules written with commonjs. <import express from "express"> is importing the default export. So the correct way is the first one, and Intellisense works with it, but code is working with with the second one.